# How to use a nested template class within a template class from a different template class

Tags: c++, templates

First, I hope the question title makes somehow sense.

I have the following class structure:

```
class A : public Singleton<A>
{
public:
    template <typename T> class Buffer
    {
    public:
         //ctor & dtor
         T* get() { return ptr; }
    private:
         T* ptr;
    };

    // class A stuff
};
```

This class should be passed to a handler class as template argument and used within the template functions of the class:

```
template <class MODEL> class Handler
{
public:
      // ctor & dtor
      template <typename T> typename MODEL::Buffer<T>* create(...) // error c2988
      { // create a buffer }
};
```

The compiler however is unable to determine the correct typenames and throws error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition (vc++ Nov 2012 CTP compiler within VS 2012). I cannot find any solution to tell the compiler how to handle the innerclass template. So the question is: How to make this work?

Any help would be highly appreciate.

Comment: I hope at least the title makes sense now (and don't put the language in the title; thats what the tags are for).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to help the compiler to disambiguate and tell it what `Buffer` is:

```
template <typename T> typename MODEL::template Buffer<T>* create(...);
//                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more info.

Comment: That was the only combination of typename/template that I didn't try! Thank you for your quick help!